# Check out these dairy-free alternatives!

Tags: discussion, collection

*This is part of a series of curated [collections](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/collection) of related questions.*

---

## Check out these dairy-free alternatives!

### Milk

- [Which plant-based milks have the highest protein content?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1519/which-plant-based-milks-have-the-highest-protein-content)
- [Hand sieve vs nut milk bag for straining plant milk](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/2149/hand-sieve-vs-nut-milk-bag-for-straining-plant-milk)
- [How do I make oat milk?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/2024/how-do-i-make-oat-milk)
- [How can I make rice mylk/milk that tastes sweet without adding sugars/sweeteners of any kind?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/how-can-i-make-rice-mylk-milk-that-tastes-sweet-without-adding-sugars-sweeteners)
- [What can substitute for cow's milk in a vegan breakfast?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/309/what-can-substitute-for-cows-milk-in-a-vegan-breakfast)
- [How can I get the same rise in baked goods when I replace cow milk with almond milk?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/550/how-can-i-get-the-same-rise-in-baked-goods-when-i-replace-cow-milk-with-almond-m)
- [How can I make a pleasant vegan latte? Soy milk often curdles in heat](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/44/how-can-i-make-a-pleasant-vegan-latte-soy-milk-often-curdles-in-heat)

### Cream

- [What can I swap for cream that's still "creamy"?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1190/what-can-i-swap-for-cream-thats-still-creamy)

### Butter

- [What do you use instead of butter (on pancakes)?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/2378/what-do-you-use-instead-of-butter-on-pancakes)
- [How can I approximate the flavour of butter in savoury dishes?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/801/how-can-i-approximate-the-flavour-of-butter-in-savoury-dishes)
- [How is vegan butter made solid?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/2322/how-is-vegan-butter-made-solid)

### Cheese

- [Experimenting with vegan cheese fermentation using real cheese crust: Is there a health risk?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/2011/experimenting-with-vegan-cheese-fermentation-using-real-cheese-crust-is-there-a)
- [How can I make vegan cream cheese using potatoes?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/2038/how-can-i-make-vegan-cream-cheese-using-potatoes)
- [Make a vegan classic poutine](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1653/make-a-vegan-classic-poutine)
- [Is there a vegan cheese I can use for pizzas?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/444/is-there-a-vegan-cheese-i-can-use-for-pizzas)
- [What are well known smoked cheese alternatives?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1097/what-are-well-known-smoked-cheese-alternatives)

### Yogurt

- [How can I make thick and creamy vegan curd or yogurt?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1990/how-can-i-make-thick-and-creamy-vegan-curd-or-yogurt)

### Dessert

- [How can I make vegan ice cream myself without expensive equipment?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1018/how-can-i-make-vegan-ice-cream-myself-without-expensive-equipment)
- [Vegan cheesecake?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1608/vegan-cheesecake)

### Infant Formula

- [Are there vegan formula options for infants?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/189/are-there-vegan-formula-options-for-infants)